# How can I add the keys of a LinkedHashMap to a JList?

Tags: java, user-interface, jlist, linkedhashmap

I have a `LinkedHashMap<String,Object>` and was wondering what the most efficient way to put the `String` portion of each element in the `LinkedHashMap` into a `JList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the [setListData(Vector)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setListData(java.util.Vector)) method:

```
jList1.setListData(new Vector<String>(map.keySet()));
```

With each of the `setListData` methods, you're making a copy of the actual data, so changes to the map will not be reflected in the list. You could instead create a custom [`ListModel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) and pass it to the [`setModel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setModel(javax.swing.ListModel)) method instead, but because there is no way to access an arbitrary element of a `LinkedHashMap` by index, this is probably infeasible.

Answer (score 1):

If the jList is not sensitive to changes of the original Map, the original method you used is fine (better than using Vector, which has the extra layer of sychronization).

If you want jList to change when the map changes, then you will have to write your own ListModel (which is not that hard).  You will also have to figure out how to know when the map changes.

Comment: What do you mean by the original method is "better than using Vector?" I'm just curious.

Comment: The Vector class has every method synchronized. This adds a small cost to each call.  It is not a big difference, but since the other technique is about as simple, I recommend it over Vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Found this way to do it just after I answered the question, thought I would put it up here for the community.  I think that this is the most efficient way to get it done, but am certainly open to more suggestions.

```
jList1.setListData(LinkedHashMap.keySet().toArray());
```

Comment: As long as you don't expect the JList to update when you add something to the map, this will work.

Comment: You could also use the setListData(Vector) method: jList1.setListData(new Vector<String>(map.keySet()));

Comment: Shall I put it in an answer, or do you want to edit it into this one?

Comment: You can go ahead and put it in an answer, I like to give credit where credit is due.